# Removing NaNs in a JSON file using python

Tags: python, json, nan, na

Json file example:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "height": null,
  "weight": NaN,
}
{
  "name": "Jim Hanks",
  "age": NaN,
  "height": NaN,
  "weight": NaN,
}
```

now imagine there are a lot of rows some containing only NaNs some containing a few NaNs.. and so on

For every row NaNs have to removed not gsubbed or anything like that

I tried approaches like using import math and isnan() but my function only gsubbed it with null.
I`m not really a python guy :/

output should be:

{
"name": "John Doe",
"age": 30,
"height": null,
}
{
"name": "Jim Hanks",
}

all help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think that your data is `json` compatible with `NaN`. Did you mean to use `null`?

Comment: `NaN` is not standard json.  So you do not actually have a json file.  Fix your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can help

```
processed_data = [remove_nans(row) for row in data]

def remove_nans(obj):
    return {key: value for key, value in obj.items() if value is not NaN and not (isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value))}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using external function to process the json file?

```py
import json

def remove_nans(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        # Recursively remove NaNs from dictionary
        return {key: remove_nans(value) for key, value in obj.items() if not (isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value))}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        # Recursively remove NaNs from list
        return [remove_nans(item) for item in obj]
    else:
        return obj

# with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
#    data = json.load(f)

data = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "height": None,
        "weight": float('nan')
    },
    {
        "name": "Jim Hanks",
        "age": float('nan'),
        "height": float('nan'),
        "weight": float('nan')
    }
]

processed_data = [remove_nans(row) for row in data]
```